# Memory management with boost asio

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, c++11, boost-asio

Quite often I find my asio event queue as follows:

```
handler_that_destroys_object()
handler_that_acts_on_object()
```

I currently get around this by storing object in a shared pointer, and using a weak pointer
to that in handler_that_acts_on_object().

I don't like this because itt forces me to use shared pointers in places where I'd rather not.

Is there a better way of getting around forcing shared pointers on the owner of the object?

For example, Using some kind of shared count to the object within the object itself,
so that using shared pointers is not forced on the allocater of the object.

What I want seems to be like weak_ptr, and shared_from_this, with the existance of the object as an implicit reference count.

## UPDATE

This seems to work as I want it too (It's probably not a good way of doing it, but just to explain what I want)

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/weak_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>

struct SelfCounting
    : boost::shared_ptr<SelfCounting>
//  , boost::noncopyable<SelfCounting> /* Does not work */
{
    int d;
};

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(SelfCounting_automatic) {
    boost::weak_ptr<SelfCounting> p;
    {
        SelfCounting t;
        p = boost::shared_ptr<SelfCounting>(t);
    }
    BOOST_CHECK(!p.lock());
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(SelfCounting_boost_sp) {
    boost::weak_ptr<SelfCounting> p;
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<SelfCounting> t(new SelfCounting());
        p = boost::shared_ptr<SelfCounting>(t);
    }
    BOOST_CHECK(!p.lock());
}
```

It runs without any complaints from valgrind, though it probably has issues.

Comment: If the ownership is not shared, why is it that the handler that acts on the object does not own it?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Edited (see  last paragraph)

Comment: Sounds like you want a boost::intrusive_ptr then.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I'm not sure how that would work. I don't want the lifetime of my object to change, but to have the handlers know when the object is destroyed

Comment: So the handler_that_acts_on_object will not do anything if the object is gone? Is multithreading involved?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes  Yes, It won't do anything and no multiple threads accessing this object.